# JSON Array to Java objects

Tags: java, json, parsing, arraylist, gson

I need to parse a JSON file which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "y": 148, 
    "x": 155
  }, 
  {
    "y": 135, 
    "x": 148
  }, 
  {
    "y": 148, 
    "x": 154
  }
]
```

And I want to put these X-coordinates and Y-coordinates into an JavaObject Click, that class looks like this:

```
public class Click {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Click(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I have looked at gson because they say it is quit easy, but I don't get it how I can do it from my file.

Comment: `[]` is an array, `{}` is an object.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

assuming your json string data is stored in variable called `jsonStr`:

```
String jsonStr = getJsonFromSomewhere();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Click clicks[] = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Click[].class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Gson API and some examples. I've put the links below!

```
String jsonString = //your json String
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type typeOfList = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Integer>>>() {}.getType();
List<Map<String, Integer>> list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, typeOfMap);

List<Click> clicks = new ArrayList<Click>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int x = list.get(i).get("x");
    int y = list.get(i).get("y");
    clicks.add(new Click(x, y));
}
```

(http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) 
(http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.5/src/test/java/com/google/gson/functional/MapTest.java)

Comment: now I have this:

private static final String filePath = ".\\data.json";
    BufferedReader br;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
 Click click = gson.fromJson(br, Click.class);
        System.out.println(click);

but it still says my json file has a wrong startingobject and ending object

Comment: I'm not sure how BufferedReader works in that method. I didn't know you could do that. That might be why you're getting the error.

Comment: Are you stuck on getting the json into a string?

Answer (score 0):

Another solid option is [Jackson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) it seems to have a pretty solid tutorial. I'm not to familiar with it, so I hope this helps.

The main idea is that it uses an object mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);
```

Step 4 should be your best bet, just realize you probably want something other than User.class

EDIT:

If you're pretty set on using Gson, perhaps looking at other similar answers will help. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933281/parsing-json-to-pojo-using-gson?rq=1) is about converting JSON to POJO (Plain Old Java Objects) and their are a few more like it floating around. Again, I'm not super familiar with these and I can try to answer some questions, but I hope this gets you where you need to go.

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: yeah I know Jackson exists but gson seems more userfriendly and faster in it's use but I just don't get it, User.class will be Click.class, that i already knew same in gson for as far as I figured out

Comment: for Jackson to work you need to also have an empty constructor for your class