# Server response JSON string list parse

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, list

I'm making HTTP requests to a server and I my response comes back as a string in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "val1"
  },
  {
    "key2": "val2"
  }
]
```

So it is given back as a string list and each 'element' in the string is a JSON string.

What is the most effective way to retrieve each json?

I'd strip the square brackets on the first and last and then do a `string.split({regex})` to get a string array but I'm not sure if that's the best way?

But the regex might get quite convoluted as I can't just split on `","` as some key value pairings could have a list as values which will also include `","` so determining when the first json actually starts might be tricky.

Are there any libraries that can help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use any JSON processing library?

Comment: Why dont you use the `org.json.JSONObject;`?

Comment: have a look at this. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array

Comment: This is JSON array containing 2 JSON objects. A JSON parser should be able to parse this out of the box. No need to spit it up somehow manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628096/json-array-to-java-objects

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer,

```
JsonArray root = new JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonArray();
```

Cheers